# Read JSONArray from JSONObject using GSON Android

Tags: android, json, gson

How to read a JSONArray from a JSONObject using GSON.

I am trying to read this JSON String:

```
String str  = { "text" : [ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "msg":"abc"

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "msg":"xyz"

    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "msg":"pqr"

    }

    ] }
```

The class is:

```
Class A {
    int id;
    String msg;
    // And setters and getters
}
```

This code does not work:

```
class Test {
            A [] text; 
        }

        Test t = gson.fromJson(response, Test.class);

        Also
        class Test {
            ArrayList<A> text =  new ArrayList<A>(); 
        }

        Test t = gson.fromJson(response, Test.class);
```

How else can i read the string using my Test class?

Please help...

Comment: Use this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create your pojo class for your json response and pass it in your code as gson.fromJson(response, Pojo.class);

Comment: Do you need further help, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your class

```
public class A {
    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    String msg;
    // And All setter and getter

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The values given as "JSON String" are values to initiate the `A` class. And they are an array of `A`s. What might work is

```
    A[] t = gson.fromJson(response, A[].class);
```

Deserializing arrays is described in [the manual, 5.4 Array Examples](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples).